# python, convert a list of data into dataframe

Tags: python

I got the data part of a txt file and store it in a list. The data should be year, data1, data2, data3. They are separated by the \t \t or \t in the original txt file because I append the data line directly. Now I want to put it into a dataframe to work on. The dataframe has three columns year, data1 and data2.

```
['2018\t  \t7,107\t4,394\t2,713', '2017\t \t16,478\t10,286\t6,192', '2016\t  \t15,944\t9,971\t5,973', '2015\t \t15,071\t9,079\t5,992', '2014\t  \t14,415\t8,596\t5,819', '2013\t \t14,259\t8,269\t5,990', '2012\t  \t14,010\t8,143\t5,867', '2011\t \t14,149\t8,126\t6,023', '2010\t  \t14,505\t7,943\t6,562', '2009\t \t14,632\t8,022\t6,610', '2008\t  \t14,207\t7,989\t6,218', '2007\t \t14,400\t8,085\t6,315', '2006\t  \t14,750\t8,017\t6,733', '2005\t \t14,497\t7,593\t6,904', '2004\t  \t14,155\t7,150\t7,005', '2003\t \t13,285\t6,457\t6,828', '2002\t  \t12,821\t6,190\t6,631', '2001\t \t12,702\t6,080\t6,622', '2000\t  \t11,942\t5,985\t5,957', '1999\t \t10,872\t5,824\t5,048', '2018\t   \t10,362\t5,793\t4,569', '2017\t \t9,546\t5,479\t4,067', '2016\t  \t9,222\t5,418\t3,804', '2015\t \t8,859\t5,363\t3,496', '2014\t  \t8,203\t5,099\t3,104', '2013\t \t7,766\t4,861\t2,905', '2012\t  \t7,091\t4,520\t2,571', '2011\t \t6,953\t4,526\t2,427', '2010\t  \t6,632\t4,509\t2,123', '2009\t \t5,929\t4,011\t1,918', '2008\t  \t5,909\t4,080\t1,829']
```

I want a dataframe at last with column names year,data1,data2,data3

Thanks.

Comment: dataframe ... as in :pandas.dataframe? why are writing it into a file then?

Comment: there are 4 values in each item (`'2018\t  \t7,107\t4,394\t2,713'`), why *the data should be year, data1, data2* (3 columns)?

Comment: I want to put it into a dataframe at last. I also tried to put it into a file and then read it into dataframe and failed.

Comment: There are four columns, year, data1, data2, data3.

Answer (score 1):

By means of `re` module and *generator* expression:

Assuming that we have data for each year.

```
In [60]: import re

In [61]: lst = ['2018\t  \t7,107\t4,394\t2,713', '2017\t \t16,478\t10,286\t6,192', '2016\t  \t15,944\t9,971\t5,973', '2015\t \t15,071\t9,079\t5,992', '
    ...: 2014\t  \t14,415\t8,596\t5,819', '2013\t \t14,259\t8,269\t5,990', '2012\t  \t14,010\t8,143\t5,867', '2011\t \t14,149\t8,126\t6,023', '2010\t  
    ...: \t14,505\t7,943\t6,562', '2009\t \t14,632\t8,022\t6,610', '2008\t  \t14,207\t7,989\t6,218', '2007\t \t14,400\t8,085\t6,315', '2006\t  \t14,750
    ...: \t8,017\t6,733', '2005\t \t14,497\t7,593\t6,904', '2004\t  \t14,155\t7,150\t7,005', '2003\t \t13,285\t6,457\t6,828', '2002\t  \t12,821\t6,190\
    ...: t6,631', '2001\t \t12,702\t6,080\t6,622', '2000\t  \t11,942\t5,985\t5,957', '1999\t \t10,872\t5,824\t5,048', '1998\t   \t10,362\t5,793\t4,569'
    ...: , '1997\t \t9,546\t5,479\t4,067', '1996\t  \t9,222\t5,418\t3,804', '1995\t \t8,859\t5,363\t3,496', '1994\t  \t8,203\t5,099\t3,104', '1993\t \t
    ...: 7,766\t4,861\t2,905', '1992\t  \t7,091\t4,520\t2,571', '1991\t \t6,953\t4,526\t2,427', '1990\t  \t6,632\t4,509\t2,123', '1989\t \t5,929\t4,011
    ...: \t1,918', '1988\t  \t5,909\t4,080\t1,829']

In [62]: pat = re.compile(r'[^\s]+')

In [63]: parsed = (pat.findall(i) for i in lst)

In [64]: df = pd.DataFrame({i[0] : i[1:] for i in parsed})

In [65]: df
Out[65]: 
    1988   1989   1990   1991   1992   1993   1994   1995   1996  ...      2010    2011    2012    2013    2014    2015    2016    2017   2018
0  5,909  5,929  6,632  6,953  7,091  7,766  8,203  8,859  9,222  ...    14,505  14,149  14,010  14,259  14,415  15,071  15,944  16,478  7,107
1  4,080  4,011  4,509  4,526  4,520  4,861  5,099  5,363  5,418  ...     7,943   8,126   8,143   8,269   8,596   9,079   9,971  10,286  4,394
2  1,829  1,918  2,123  2,427  2,571  2,905  3,104  3,496  3,804  ...     6,562   6,023   5,867   5,990   5,819   5,992   5,973   6,192  2,713

[3 rows x 31 columns]
```

Comment: the regex partitions each `['2018\t  \t7,107\t4,394\t2,713',...]` into `[['2018','7,107','4,394','2,713'],...]` and your dict comprehension is on the fly when feeding the dataframe?

Comment: I have several groups of year 1988-2018, but at last the code only keeps the last one group of 1988-2018 and loses the others. I understand the meaning of get all the numbers in parsed. Don't understand the last line of code "df = pd.DataFrame({i[0] : i[1:] for i in parsed})". Maybe this make the code wrong.

Comment: @zilong, what does mean your *several groups of year 1988-2018* (the data is concrete)? you should learn about `dict` comprehension before considering that something *makes code wrong*

Comment: That means a panel data. Maybe the value of dictionary keeps changing when there are new data and hence, keeps the last time series at last. Yeah, my fault, I should put a short panel in my data sample in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate way without regex (but not as neat as [Romans answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51221288/7505395)), clean up your data using list comprehensions and then into a dict to create the dataframe from it:

```
data =  ['2018\t  \t7,107\t4,394\t2,713',              '2017\t \t16,478\t10,286\t6,192', 
         '2016\t  \t15,944\t9,971\t5,973',             '2015\t \t15,071\t9,079\t5,992', 
         '2014\t  \t14,415\t8,596\t5,819',             '2013\t \t14,259\t8,269\t5,990', 
         '2012\t  \t14,010\t8,143\t5,867',             '2011\t \t14,149\t8,126\t6,023', 
         '2010\t  \t14,505\t7,943\t6,562',             '2009\t \t14,632\t8,022\t6,610', 
         '2008\t  \t14,207\t7,989\t6,218',             '2007\t \t14,400\t8,085\t6,315', 
         '2006\t  \t14,750\t8,017\t6,733',             '2005\t \t14,497\t7,593\t6,904', 
         '2004\t  \t14,155\t7,150\t7,005',             '2003\t \t13,285\t6,457\t6,828', 
         '2002\t  \t12,821\t6,190\t6,631',             '2001\t \t12,702\t6,080\t6,622', 
         '2000\t  \t11,942\t5,985\t5,957',             '1999\t \t10,872\t5,824\t5,048', 
         '1998\t   \t10,362\t5,793\t4,569',            '1997\t \t9,546\t5,479\t4,067', 
         '1996\t  \t9,222\t5,418\t3,804',              '1995\t \t8,859\t5,363\t3,496', 
         '1994\t  \t8,203\t5,099\t3,104',              '1993\t \t7,766\t4,861\t2,905', 
         '1992\t  \t7,091\t4,520\t2,571',              '1991\t \t6,953\t4,526\t2,427', 
         '1990\t  \t6,632\t4,509\t2,123',              '1989\t \t5,929\t4,011\t1,918', 
         '1988\t  \t5,909\t4,080\t1,829']

# partition and clean the data
cleaned = [ [x.strip() for x in year.split("\t") if x.strip()] for year in data  ]
# make a dict
dataCleaned = {x:y for x,*y in cleaned}

print (dataCleaned)

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dataCleaned)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
# the dict 
{'2018': ['7,107', '4,394', '2,713'], '2017': ['16,478', '10,286', '6,192'], 
 '2016': ['15,944', '9,971', '5,973'], '2015': ['15,071', '9,079', '5,992'], 
 '2014': ['14,415', '8,596', '5,819'], '2013': ['14,259', '8,269', '5,990'], 
 '2012': ['14,010', '8,143', '5,867'], '2011': ['14,149', '8,126', '6,023'], 
 '2010': ['14,505', '7,943', '6,562'], '2009': ['14,632', '8,022', '6,610'], 
 '2008': ['14,207', '7,989', '6,218'], '2007': ['14,400', '8,085', '6,315'], 
 '2006': ['14,750', '8,017', '6,733'], '2005': ['14,497', '7,593', '6,904'], 
 '2004': ['14,155', '7,150', '7,005'], '2003': ['13,285', '6,457', '6,828'], 
 '2002': ['12,821', '6,190', '6,631'], '2001': ['12,702', '6,080', '6,622'], 
 '2000': ['11,942', '5,985', '5,957'], '1999': ['10,872', '5,824', '5,048'], 
 '1998': ['10,362', '5,793', '4,569'], '1997': ['9,546', '5,479', '4,067'], 
 '1996': ['9,222', '5,418', '3,804'], '1995': ['8,859', '5,363', '3,496'], 
 '1994': ['8,203', '5,099', '3,104'], '1993': ['7,766', '4,861', '2,905'], 
 '1992': ['7,091', '4,520', '2,571'], '1991': ['6,953', '4,526', '2,427'], 
 '1990': ['6,632', '4,509', '2,123'], '1989': ['5,929', '4,011', '1,918'], 
 '1988': ['5,909', '4,080', '1,829']
```

}

```
# the dataframe
    1988   1989   1990   1991   1992   1993   1994   1995   1996   1997  \
0  5,909  5,929  6,632  6,953  7,091  7,766  8,203  8,859  9,222  9,546
1  4,080  4,011  4,509  4,526  4,520  4,861  5,099  5,363  5,418  5,479
2  1,829  1,918  2,123  2,427  2,571  2,905  3,104  3,496  3,804  4,067

   ...      2009    2010    2011    2012    2013    2014    2015    2016  \
0  ...    14,632  14,505  14,149  14,010  14,259  14,415  15,071  15,944
1  ...     8,022   7,943   8,126   8,143   8,269   8,596   9,079   9,971
2  ...     6,610   6,562   6,023   5,867   5,990   5,819   5,992   5,973

     2017   2018
0  16,478  7,107
1  10,286  4,394
2   6,192  2,713

[3 rows x 31 columns]
```

---

After your edit:

```
import pandas as pd

data = ['2018\t  \t7,107\t4,394\t2,713', '2017\t \t16,478\t10,286\t6,192', 
        '2016\t  \t15,944\t9,971\t5,973', '2015\t \t15,071\t9,079\t5,992', 
        '2014\t  \t14,415\t8,596\t5,819', '2013\t \t14,259\t8,269\t5,990', 
        '2012\t  \t14,010\t8,143\t5,867', '2011\t \t14,149\t8,126\t6,023', 
        '2010\t  \t14,505\t7,943\t6,562', '2009\t \t14,632\t8,022\t6,610', 
        '2008\t  \t14,207\t7,989\t6,218', '2007\t \t14,400\t8,085\t6,315', 
        '2006\t  \t14,750\t8,017\t6,733', '2005\t \t14,497\t7,593\t6,904', 
        '2004\t  \t14,155\t7,150\t7,005', '2003\t \t13,285\t6,457\t6,828', 
        '2002\t  \t12,821\t6,190\t6,631', '2001\t \t12,702\t6,080\t6,622', 
        '2000\t  \t11,942\t5,985\t5,957', '1999\t \t10,872\t5,824\t5,048', 
        '2018\t   \t10,362\t5,793\t4,569', '2017\t \t9,546\t5,479\t4,067', 
        '2016\t  \t9,222\t5,418\t3,804', '2015\t \t8,859\t5,363\t3,496', 
        '2014\t  \t8,203\t5,099\t3,104', '2013\t \t7,766\t4,861\t2,905', 
        '2012\t  \t7,091\t4,520\t2,571', '2011\t \t6,953\t4,526\t2,427', 
        '2010\t  \t6,632\t4,509\t2,123', '2009\t \t5,929\t4,011\t1,918', 
        '2008\t  \t5,909\t4,080\t1,829']

# partition and clean the data
cleaned = [ [x.strip() for x in year.split("\t") if x.strip()] for year in data  ]

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(cleaned,columns=['year', 'data1', 'data2', 'data3'])

print(df)
```

Output after Edit:

```
    year   data1   data2  data3
0   2018   7,107   4,394  2,713
1   2017  16,478  10,286  6,192
2   2016  15,944   9,971  5,973
3   2015  15,071   9,079  5,992
4   2014  14,415   8,596  5,819
5   2013  14,259   8,269  5,990
6   2012  14,010   8,143  5,867
7   2011  14,149   8,126  6,023
8   2010  14,505   7,943  6,562
9   2009  14,632   8,022  6,610
10  2008  14,207   7,989  6,218
11  2007  14,400   8,085  6,315
12  2006  14,750   8,017  6,733
13  2005  14,497   7,593  6,904
14  2004  14,155   7,150  7,005
15  2003  13,285   6,457  6,828
16  2002  12,821   6,190  6,631
17  2001  12,702   6,080  6,622
18  2000  11,942   5,985  5,957
19  1999  10,872   5,824  5,048
20  2018  10,362   5,793  4,569
21  2017   9,546   5,479  4,067
22  2016   9,222   5,418  3,804
23  2015   8,859   5,363  3,496
24  2014   8,203   5,099  3,104
25  2013   7,766   4,861  2,905
26  2012   7,091   4,520  2,571
27  2011   6,953   4,526  2,427
28  2010   6,632   4,509  2,123
29  2009   5,929   4,011  1,918
30  2008   5,909   4,080  1,829
```

---

Edit:

```
cleaned = [ [x.strip() for x in year.split("\t") if x.strip()] for year in data  ]
```

is about the same as:

```
alsoCleaned = []
for year in data:
    part = []    # collect all parts of one string
    for x in year.split("\t"):  # split the one string
        partCleaned = x.strip()   # remove whitespaces from x
        if partCleaned :          # only if now got content
            part.append(partCleaned) # add to part
    alsoCleaned.append(part)    # done all parts  so add to big list
    part = []

print(alsoCleaned)
```

==>

```
[['2018', '7,107', '4,394', '2,713'], ['2017', '16,478', '10,286', '6,192'], 
 # .... and so on ...., 
 ['2008', '5,909', '4,080', '1,829']]
```

Comment: My real data is long and has several groups of year 1988-2018 and the code at last only has one group of year 1988-2018 data and lose the others.

Comment: @zilong why do you prepare and post data in your questions that does not fit your real data? Edited - see additional answer for fixed column-names.

Comment: Sorry. My data is too long and I have to copy a part of it here to make the question short. However, I failed to keep the data representative at the first time.  Thank you very much. Problem solved.

Comment: I still couldn't understand this important line of code. I know strp() gets ride of whitespace and split() splits by \t. What does the "for year in data", "x in year" mean? Or what should I learn to understand this (maybe some webpage or resource).cleaned = [ [x.strip() for x in year.split("\t") if x.strip()] for year in data  ]

Comment: @zilong - its called a list comprehension. you have to read it kind of backwards. `data` is a list. `for year in data` means that `year` will take every value of data after the other. `[x.strip() for x in year.split("\t") if x.strip()]` means - split `year` at '|' (gives another list in return) and `for x in yearl.split('|')` means x will in turn take the value of every split part. 'x.strip()' removes the whitespaces and `if x.strip()` only matches for x that are not empty after stripping them (removes the `'\t  \t'` whitespace from the result).

Comment: @zilong  - see edit: this would be the "non-list-comprehension" code that does about the same. [doku for list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)